# Unable To Send Emails Via Amazon SES to Unverified Email Addresses Even After Being Move From Sandbox To Production

Tags: phpmailer, amazon-ses

Even after being moved from the Sandbox environment to production, I'm still unable to send emails via Amazon SES using PhpMailer to unverified email addresses. However, I can send it to verified email addresses. PhpMailer gives an error:

```
SMTP Error: data not accepted
```

Any possible reasons why?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide extra information regarding your specific use case?
In my experience, we are using SMTP configuration in ec2 instances that need to be able to send emails, and configuring the correct user/password on the SMTP file allowed us to send such emails, we had the problem of SES rejecting with an "explicit" message mails to unverified accounts while on sandbox mode but that problem ceased to exist after switching into production mode without changing anything else.

your configuration for PHP mailer should look like something like this:

```
$mail->IsSMTP(true);
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Host= "email-smtp.YOURREGIONHERE.amazonaws.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'YOURIDHERE';
$mail->Password = 'YOURSECRETHERE'
```

if not TLS the port should be 25
the error that you are getting usually means a lot of things so I think you should add the following to your code and check the error message

```
$email->SMTPDebug = true;
```